# want to add a field to a timestamp with DATE_ADD

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timestamp, dateadd

i want to add a column named column_ourcountry_time that will show the timestamp of the time when each row is created DATE_ADD INTERVAL 10 HOUR to current time of server in each row.

when i use the TIMESTAMP it saves the current server time,its ok,but i want to store the timestamp of our country,thats +10 hours to the server time.anyone help me get through it.
thanks in advance
yours faithfully
Aiman

Comment: change your default timezone in php file 'http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php'

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like

```
select addtime(now(), '10:00:00');
```

because that adds time and keeps days like they are (24 hours) etc.

If the '10:00:00' part is a variable '10' in another column `timezone_offset`, I think you can use this:

```
select addtime(now(), concat(timezone_offset, ':00:00')) from table;
```

-- edit 1

Depending on timezone_offset and the timezone of your MySQL server, you might have to alter timezone_offset before you use addtime:

If MySQL runs `UTC +1` and you save `timezone_offset compared to UTC`, you have to alter all `timezone_offset -1`, because `now()` isn't UTC timezone.

-- edit 2

I find it a best practice to store ALL times in UTC because that's the easiest to calculate from and to. If you're doing anything with timezones and offsets: do everything UTC. (Make sure your MySQL server has UTC as timezone as well.)

Comment: i want to create/add a colum that will automatically update when the row is updated or inserted.the row should show the time when the row was inserted or updated.just want to see 10 hours added to the current timestamp,thanks for the co-operation..:)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT NOW() + INTERVAL 10 HOUR
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use

```
SET  time_zone = '+10:00'
```

read here 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html